# Unable to add hotmail/outlook user in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: outlook, azure-devops, microsoft-account

I am trying to add user having Hotmail account but team foundation showing following error.

Can anybody please tell me that how can I add another user in VSTS?

[image: Getting the following message while adding user]

> No identities found.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how your account was set up. If it's Microsoft Account based (LiveID/Outlook.com/Hotmail), then you need to navigate to the account level users hub first.

```
https://{{account}}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_users
```

If your account is Azure Active Directory backed, then you need to import these users into [Azure Active Directory first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-what-is-azure-ad-b2b), then add them at the account level before being able to add them to a security group.